# Sharepoint Online Change WebPart View Query using C# / CSOM

Tags: c#, web-parts, sharepoint-online, csom

I have try to change default view query using C# but it's not working. I can change JSLink property, but not XmlDefinition. Any idea to workaround or what I'm doing wrong?

```
var webPart = listWebPart.WebPart.
clientContext.Load(webPart.Properties);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();    
webPart.Properties["XmlDefinition"] = newQuery;
listWebPart.SaveWebPartChanges();
clientContext.Load(listWebPart);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

It's list webpart on some page.

Comment: With on-premise installation you would use LimitedWebPartManager to retreive the view and with reflection and xml node modification change it. Sample answer https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/206309/how-to-modify-xsltlistviewwebpart-xmldefinition-property-using-powershell/212387 . Hope this helps a little.

Comment: Yes, on-premise is easier to make change. I have problems on online. I tried already reflection - null is returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the `LimitedWebPartManager` for the page with the `GetLimitedWebPartManager` function on SharePoint Online as well, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.getlimitedwebpartmanager.aspx). You can then load the WebParts using the `LimitedWebPartManager` as below:

```
var page = ctx.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(pageUrl);
LimitedWebPartManager wpMgr = page.GetLimitedWebPartManager(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
ctx.Load(wpMgr.WebParts);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

This will load all the webparts on the page. You can then get the `WebPartDefinition` of the webpart you require using it's index:

```
WebPartDefinition webPartDef = wpMgr.WebParts[webpartIndex];
ctx.Load(webPartDef);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

You can now finally update the desired property and save the definition:

```
webPartDef.WebPart.Properties["XmlDefinition"] = newQuery;
webPartDef.SaveWebPartChanges();
webPartDef.CloseWebPart();
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Hopefully this will help you update your webpart properties